# Linear mixed effect model : formula and difference between random effect and within subject effect

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I want to explain the variablity of my continuous dependent variable `a` with two independent variables:

one between subjects variable `b`

one within subjects variable `c`

So I am using a linear mixed model but I am not sure about the formula. Should I use:

1) `a ~ b + (1|c)`

or

2) `a ~ b*c + (1|c)`

Also Is there a difference between within subjects effect and random effect or are they always synonyms?

Comment: you should define a variable indicating the subjects. that's what you should put after the bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of your model formulations make sense.

Both `b` and `c` should be treated as fixed effects.

Since observations are repeated within subjects, you should use the subject ID as the grouping variable.

So, the following model would be a good place to start:

```
a ~ b + c + (1 | subjectID)
```

which will fit random intercepts for each subject.

> Also Is there a difference between within subjects effect and random effect or are they always synonyms?

A variable that varies within subjects should be treated as a fixed effect as above, and possibly also with random slopes, for example with:

```
a ~ b + c + (1 + c | subjectID)
```

which will allow the slope of `c` to vary for each subject, provided that the data support such a model.